# Lamp: Phpmyadmin shows blank page, localhost page is working

Tags: phpmyadmin, localhost, lamp, ubuntu-15.10

I installed lamp in ubuntu 15.10 according to the link http://sourcedigit.com/17602-install-lamp-on-ubuntu-15-10-desktop-using-terminal/ .localhost page is working but whenever I run http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ it shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You may find `https://askubuntu.com/` which is very helpful in regard of solving ubuntu related problem.

It can be denoted that `https://askubuntu.com/` is a part of `stackoverflow.com` as well as precisely built for Ubuntu related queries/questions.
Here is a link helps you I guess:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/55280/phpmyadmin-is-not-working-after-i-installed-it

This may resolves your issue:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin
sudo service apache2 restart
```

With Regards.